# How do I setup a PubSub chat system using EventMachine?

Tags: websocket, eventmachine, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to learn `EventMachine` (and become a better, asynchronous programmer).  I thought I would go with the classic `chat app`.

I manged to setup a WebSocket (using `em-websocke`t) server and a WebSocket client.  All was great until I realized that `most browsers don't support WebSocket!`  Especially IE.  My curse for using Chrome everywhere.  lol

So, how can I use EventMachine as my server (to receive incoming messages) and be able to send messages back to subscribed clients?

Plus, I want this to work in any browser.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the `em-websocket` project has an [example of a WebSocket client using flash fallback](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket/blob/master/examples/test.html) if WebSockets are not available. I haven't actually tried this, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We created Pusher (http://pusher.com/) partially to solve this issue of compatibility. We have a flashsocket fallback for non-supported browsers and also support for the different websocket protocol versions. Although you might not need to use EM with Pusher, you might still find it useful for playing with realtime messaging!

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping for a non commercial system.